# Does the Samsung Galaxy S have an FM transmitter?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, fm-radio

I seem to recall seeing a review of the Samsung Galaxy S that said it has an FM transmitter (so you can listen to music from it on your car radio, for instance).  However, I didn't see it mentioned anywhere else.

Does it in fact have such a transmitter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Early promotional material for the Galaxy S said that it had an FM transmitter.  Samsung later removed this from the list of features.  Some models, such as the i9000, have a FM **receiver**.  It appears other versions also have a receiver that is not supported by drivers;  [This XDA thread](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=738318) has more details.

Your best bet is to get an FM transmitter than plugs into the headphone jack, or to use Bluetooth.

Answer (score 2):

If your looking for a bluetooth solution, It might be possible VIA [This](http://www.samsunggalaxysforum.com/index.php?topic=1690.0)

But does it have a FM transmitter out of the box, no.